# Bootstrap's Modal UI issue in IE browser

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I am developing a web project. In this project i am displaying some user's roles in bootstrap's modal popup but that data is displaying in a straight line rather than new line in all browser's except Chrome. Chrome is displaying fine as expected. Please give me any solution.
Thanks.
Please view my following snapshot.
[Application's bug snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsAxh.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your containing the elements all the way to the outside, that bootstrap needs, so that the styles will apply completely.  I suspect this might be the cause.

*Try using the nav-stack class*.  This is found here on this stack article
[Vertical Menu in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381965/vertical-menu-in-bootstrap)

*You want to make sure you have the entire box model for the nav in tact, for all dependency styles*.

Comment: Thanks for answer me. problem is still not solved i am displaying data as vertical instead of horizontal thanks